# Python error: "ValueError: cannot switch from manual field specification to automatic field numbering" and I don't know why

Tags: python, large-files

I have been working on making a multiplication table using a function, a for loop and string formatting. I tried a small-scale test table going up to twenty, which printed fine. then, I went all the way up to 100, and I got this error: "ValueError: cannot switch from manual field specification to automatic field numbering" and I don't know why. I do have a very large code, and I may have made some spelling mistakes. I realize that there is probably an easier way of doing it, but I am just unaware of it. I don't know advanced Python methods, sadly.
Here is the up-to-twenty code which I wrote:

```
def createtable():
    layout = "{0:>5} {1:>5} {2:>5} {3:>5} {4:>5} {5:>5} {6:>5} {7:>5} {8:>5} {9:>5} {10:>5} {11:>5} {12:>5} {13:>5} {14:>5} {15:>5} {16:>5} {17:>5} {18:>5} {19:>5} {20:>5}"
    print(layout.format(" ","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20"))
    print("    |------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    for i in range(1,21):
        print(layout.format(str(i)+"|",1*i,2*i,3*i,4*i,5*i,6*i,7*i,8*i,9*i,10*i,11*i,12*i,13*i,14*i,15*i,16*i,17*i,18*i,19*i,20*i))
```

and here is the code that I couldn't get to work:

```
def createtable2():
    layout = "{0:>5} {1:>5} {2:>5} {3:>5} {4:>5} {5:>5} {6:>5} {7:>5} {8:>5} {9:>5} {10:>5} {11:>5} {12:>5} {13:>5} {14:>5} {15:>5} {16:>5} {17:>5} {18:>5} {19:>5} {20:>5} {21:>5} {22:>5} {23:>5} {24:>5} {25:>5} {26:>5} {27:>5} {28:>5} {29:>5} {30:>5} {31:>5} {32:>5} {34:>5} {35:>5} {36:>5} {37:>5} {38:>5} {39:>5} {40:>5} {41:>5} {42:>5} {:43>5} {44:>5} {45:>5} {46:>5} {47:>5} {48:>5} {49:>5} {50:>5} {51:>5} {52:>5} {53:>5} {54:>5} {55:>5} {56:>5} {57:>5} {58:>5} {59:>5} {60:>5} {61:>5} {62:>5} {63:>5} {64:>5} {65:>5} {66:>5} {67:>5} {68:>5} {69:>5} {70:>5} {71:>5} {72:>5} {73:>5} {74:>5} {75:>5} {76:>5} {77:>5} {78:>5} {79:>5} {80:>5} {81:>5} {82:>5} {83:>5} {84:>5} {85:>5} {86:>5} {87:>5} {89:>5} {90:>5} {91:>5} {92:>5} {93:>5} {94:>5} {95:>5} {96:>5} {97:>5} {98:>5} {99:>5} {100:>5}"
    print(layout.format(" ","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31","32","33","34","35","36","37","38","39","40","41","42","43","44","45","46","47","48","49","50","51","52","53","54","55","56","57","58","59","60","61","62","63","64","65","66","67","68","69","70","71","72","73","74","75","76","77","78","79","80","81","82","83","84","85","86","87","88","89","90","91","92","93","94","95","96","97","98","99","100"))
    print("    |------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    for i in range(1,21):
        print(layout.format(str(i)+"|",1*i,2*i,3*i,4*i,5*i,6*i,7*i,8*i,9*i,10*i,11*i,12*i,13*i,14*i,15*i,16*i,17*i,18*i,19*i,20*i))
```

I don't know what is wrong. Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You made 3 typos in `layout`:

1. You are missing `{33:>5}`
2. You are missing `{88:>5}`
3. You wrote `{:43>5}` instead of `{43:>5}`

It is the final typo that gave rise to the error message you see.

This simply goes to show that manually typing in such a long list is a bad idea as you have a high risk of doing something wrong.

Additionally, the length of `layout` must match the number of arguments you pass to `layout.format`. Because of this, you would have gotten another error in the for loop, as the number of arguments in the final `layout.format` is 21, whereas the `layout` variable has length 101 (without typos).

I would recommend a generalized approach to such a problem instead, removing the risk of passing a wrong number of arguments, and creating typos. See example below:

```py
def create_table(max_row, max_col):
    layout = ' '.join([f'{{{x}:>5}}' for x in range(max_col + 1)])
    fmt = [str(x) for x in range(1, max_col + 1)]
    print(layout.format(" ", *fmt))
    brk = '------' * max_col

    print(f"    |{brk}")
    for i in range(1, max_row + 1):
        cols = [x * i for x in range(1, max_col + 1)]
        print(layout.format(str(i) + "|", *cols))
```

```py
>>> create_table(max_row=24, max_col=15)

          1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13    14    15
    |------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1|     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12    13    14    15
   2|     2     4     6     8    10    12    14    16    18    20    22    24    26    28    30
   3|     3     6     9    12    15    18    21    24    27    30    33    36    39    42    45
   4|     4     8    12    16    20    24    28    32    36    40    44    48    52    56    60
   5|     5    10    15    20    25    30    35    40    45    50    55    60    65    70    75
   6|     6    12    18    24    30    36    42    48    54    60    66    72    78    84    90
   7|     7    14    21    28    35    42    49    56    63    70    77    84    91    98   105
   8|     8    16    24    32    40    48    56    64    72    80    88    96   104   112   120
   9|     9    18    27    36    45    54    63    72    81    90    99   108   117   126   135
  10|    10    20    30    40    50    60    70    80    90   100   110   120   130   140   150
  11|    11    22    33    44    55    66    77    88    99   110   121   132   143   154   165
  12|    12    24    36    48    60    72    84    96   108   120   132   144   156   168   180
  13|    13    26    39    52    65    78    91   104   117   130   143   156   169   182   195
  14|    14    28    42    56    70    84    98   112   126   140   154   168   182   196   210
  15|    15    30    45    60    75    90   105   120   135   150   165   180   195   210   225
  16|    16    32    48    64    80    96   112   128   144   160   176   192   208   224   240
  17|    17    34    51    68    85   102   119   136   153   170   187   204   221   238   255
  18|    18    36    54    72    90   108   126   144   162   180   198   216   234   252   270
  19|    19    38    57    76    95   114   133   152   171   190   209   228   247   266   285
  20|    20    40    60    80   100   120   140   160   180   200   220   240   260   280   300
  21|    21    42    63    84   105   126   147   168   189   210   231   252   273   294   315
  22|    22    44    66    88   110   132   154   176   198   220   242   264   286   308   330
  23|    23    46    69    92   115   138   161   184   207   230   253   276   299   322   345
  24|    24    48    72    96   120   144   168   192   216   240   264   288   312   336   360
```